# Using spatial data methods in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use spatial data methods in LINQ, System.Data.Spatial isn't showing up as an option for the using declaration. It doesn't show up as an option for references either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

I added the NuGet Package System.Data for OData v1-3. Could that have caused the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should reference `System.Data.Entity` assembly, in which this namespace is defined.

Comment: Thanks! I found this out just before you answered.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Entity Framework 6.0 doesn't use System.Data.Spatial. It now uses System.Data.Entity.Spatial.